# gamma_imp() function is not working with the latest version of boost library (version 1_78)

Tags: c++, boost, gamma-function

I am updating the boost library to latest version for our source code and came across this problem where the last parameter to gamma_imp() function (present in <boost\math\special_functions\gamma.hpp>) isn't available in boost anymore.
The last parameter is a variable of type `boost::math::lanczos::lanczos22`.
But the `lanczos22`class that used to be declared in <boost\math\special_functions\lanczos.hpp> isn't available in the latest version anymore.

I tried to look at the release notes in https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_78_0.html and it doesn't have any information on it.

How do I go about this issue? Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: You should probably be using `lanczos<Real, Policy>::type` instead of `lanczos22` directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, I can try that!